# Convert Date Ranges to Time Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My raw data looks like the following:

```
  start_date   end_date  value
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-03      2
1 2016-01-05 2016-01-08      4
```

The interpretation is that the data takes a value of **2** between **1/1/2016** and **1/3/2016**, and it takes a value of **4** between **1/5/2016** and **1/8/2016**.  I want to transform the raw data to a daily time series like the following:

```
2016-01-01    2
2016-01-02    2
2016-01-03    2
2016-01-04    0
2016-01-05    4
2016-01-06    4
2016-01-07    4
2016-01-08    4
```

Note that if a date in the time series doesn't appear between the **start_date** and **end_date** in any row of the raw data, it gets a value of 0 in the time series.

I can create the time series by looping through the raw data, but that's slow.  Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: please check your expected output or this condition `if a date doesn't appear in the raw data, it gets a value of 0` - why do you have `values != 0` for the dates: 01,02,05,06,07?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Hopefully the edits make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
  start_date   end_date  value
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-03      2
1 2016-01-05 2016-01-08      4

In [121]: new = pd.DataFrame({'dt': pd.date_range(df.start_date.min(), df.end_date.max())})

In [122]: new
Out[122]:
          dt
0 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-02
2 2016-01-03
3 2016-01-04
4 2016-01-05
5 2016-01-06
6 2016-01-07
7 2016-01-08

In [123]: new = new.merge(df, how='left', left_on='dt', right_on='start_date').fillna(method='pad')

In [124]: new
Out[124]:
          dt start_date   end_date  value
0 2016-01-01 2016-01-01 2016-01-03    2.0
1 2016-01-02 2016-01-01 2016-01-03    2.0
2 2016-01-03 2016-01-01 2016-01-03    2.0
3 2016-01-04 2016-01-01 2016-01-03    2.0
4 2016-01-05 2016-01-05 2016-01-08    4.0
5 2016-01-06 2016-01-05 2016-01-08    4.0
6 2016-01-07 2016-01-05 2016-01-08    4.0
7 2016-01-08 2016-01-05 2016-01-08    4.0

In [125]: new.ix[(new.dt < new.start_date) | (new.dt > new.end_date), 'value'] = 0

In [126]: new[['dt', 'value']]
Out[126]:
          dt  value
0 2016-01-01    2.0
1 2016-01-02    2.0
2 2016-01-03    2.0
3 2016-01-04    0.0
4 2016-01-05    4.0
5 2016-01-06    4.0
6 2016-01-07    4.0
7 2016-01-08    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's orders of magnitude faster than the loop I was using.

Comment: @hahdawg, glad I could help :)