# Python: fast aggregation of many observations to daily sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have observations with start and end date of the following format:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date':pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-07','2021-01-04','2021-01-12','2021-01-03']),
    'end_date':pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-16','2021-01-12','2021-01-13','2021-01-15']),
    'value':[7,6,5,4]
    })

data

    start_date  end_date    value
0   2021-01-07  2021-01-16  7
1   2021-01-04  2021-01-12  6
2   2021-01-12  2021-01-13  5
3   2021-01-03  2021-01-15  4
```

The date ranges between observations overlap. I would like to compute the daily sum aggregated across all observations.

My version with a loop (below) is slow and crashes for ~100k observations. What would be a way to speed things up?

```
def turn_data_into_date_range(row):
  dates = pd.date_range(start=row.start_date, end=row.end_date)
  return pd.Series(data=row.value, index=dates)

out = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  out.append(turn_data_into_date_range(row))

result = pd.concat(out, axis=1).sum(axis=1)

result
2021-01-03     4.0
2021-01-04    10.0
2021-01-05    10.0
2021-01-06    10.0
2021-01-07    17.0
2021-01-08    17.0
2021-01-09    17.0
2021-01-10    17.0
2021-01-11    17.0
2021-01-12    22.0
2021-01-13    16.0
2021-01-14    11.0
2021-01-15    11.0
2021-01-16     7.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

PS: [the answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187637/convert-date-ranges-to-time-series-in-pandas) doesn't work in my case, as they have non-overlapping observations and can use a left join: [Convert Date Ranges to Time Series in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187637/convert-date-ranges-to-time-series-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel this problem comes back regularly as it’s not an easy thing to do. Some techniques would probably transform each row into a date range or otherwise iterate on rows. In this case there’s a smarter workaround, which is to use cumulative sums, then reindex.

```
>>> starts = data.set_index('start_date')['value'].sort_index().cumsum()
>>> starts
start_date
2021-01-03     4
2021-01-04    10
2021-01-07    17
2021-01-12    22
Name: value, dtype: int64
>>> ends = data.set_index('end_date')['value'].sort_index().cumsum()
>>> ends
end_date
2021-01-12     6
2021-01-13    11
2021-01-15    15
2021-01-16    22
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

In case your dates are not unique, you could group by by date and sum first. Then the series definitions are as follows:

```
>>> starts = data.groupby('start_date')['value'].sum().sort_index().cumsum()
>>> ends = data.groupby('end_date')['value'].sum().sort_index().cumsum()
```

Note that here we don’t need the `set_index()` anymore which is done by `sum()` as it is an aggregation, contrarily to `.cumsum()`which is a transform operation.

Of course if the `ends` are inclusive you might need to add a `.shift()`:

```
>>> dates = pd.date_range(starts.index.min(), ends.index.max())
>>> ends.reindex(dates).ffill().shift().fillna(0)
2021-01-03     0.0
2021-01-04     0.0
2021-01-05     0.0
2021-01-06     0.0
2021-01-07     0.0
2021-01-08     0.0
2021-01-09     0.0
2021-01-10     0.0
2021-01-11     0.0
2021-01-12     0.0
2021-01-13     6.0
2021-01-14    11.0
2021-01-15    11.0
2021-01-16    15.0
Freq: D, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Then just subtract the (possibly shifted) ends from the starts:

```
>>> starts.reindex(dates).ffill() - ends.reindex(dates).ffill().shift().fillna(0)
2021-01-03     4.0
2021-01-04    10.0
2021-01-05    10.0
2021-01-06    10.0
2021-01-07    17.0
2021-01-08    17.0
2021-01-09    17.0
2021-01-10    17.0
2021-01-11    17.0
2021-01-12    22.0
2021-01-13    16.0
2021-01-14    11.0
2021-01-15    11.0
2021-01-16     7.0
Freq: D, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi, this answer looks really promising, thanks! I have tried it on my full dataset and it throws an error because the start_date and end_date columns are not unique. Would you have a tip for that case?

Comment: @curious_know_nothing I’ve added something to handle that. It’s roughly what @ALoliz suggested but earlier and with `.sum()` instead of `.max()`

Comment: Thanks, this is great! On my real dataset the speedup is >1000x!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to break each range into individual days:

```py
data['day'] = data.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_date'], row['end_date']), axis=1)
result = data[['day', 'value']].explode('day').groupby('day').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

*What would be a way to speed things up?*

You did

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  out.append(turn_data_into_date_range(row))
```

practical usage show that it is possible to get speed increase from using `.itertuples()` rather than `.iterrows()` see [Why Pandas itertuples() Is Faster Than iterrows() and How To Make It Even Faster](https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d). I suggest reworking your code to use said `.itertuples()` method. I do not have ability to test it now, but I suspect your `turn_data_into_date_range` function might work without any changes, as said tuples support access via dot attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@Cimbali's solution is a more efficient option.

One option is to solve this with an inequality join, using the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# Build a Series of all the dates:
dates = data.filter(like='date')
start = dates.min().min()
end = dates.max().max()
dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D', name = 'dates')
dates = pd.Series(dates)

(data
.conditional_join(
    dates, 
    ('start_date', 'dates', '<='), 
    ('end_date', 'dates', '>='), 
    # numba might offer more performance
    use_numba=False, 
    df_columns='value')
.groupby('dates')
.sum()
)

            value
dates
2021-01-03      4
2021-01-04     10
2021-01-05     10
2021-01-06     10
2021-01-07     17
2021-01-08     17
2021-01-09     17
2021-01-10     17
2021-01-11     17
2021-01-12     22
2021-01-13     16
2021-01-14     11
2021-01-15     11
2021-01-16      7
```